# Downgrading package with pip produces ValueError('Expected Version spec in',

Tags: pip, downgrade

On an Ubuntu 12.04 system where I don't have sudo rights, I've setup a virtual environment so I can have up to date python packages. The system virtualenv installed a pretty old version of pip into it (1.1) which I upgraded to 6.1.1.

I find now that if I try to specify a package version with something like:

```
pip install pymongo=2.6.2
```

pip throws a `ValueError('Expected version spec in', 'pymongo=2.6.2', 'at', '=2.6.2')

Answer (score 27):

The syntax for specifying a version is `package==versionSpec` with TWO equals signs, so I should have done:

```
pip install pymongo==2.6.2
```